# Como obtener la fecha maxima de un arreglo limitandolo a la fecha actual. Es decir quiero encontrar la fecha mas grande pero que no sea mayor que hoy

Tags: java, spring-boot

hice esto pero me trae la mas grande sin importar el dia de hoy.

```
Date maxDate = listUsuarioDetalleHoraDto.stream().map(u -> u.getFecha()).max(Date::compareTo).get();
```

Comment: Titulo = Idea general. Cuerpo del mensaje = detalles. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar un filtro antes de obtener el resultado maximo, por ejemplo:

```
Date result = arrayDate.stream().filter(x -> !x.equals(fechaActual) && x.before(fechaActual)).max(Date::compareTo).get();
```

Lo que estamos haciendo en el filtro es traer las fechas que no sean iguales a la fecha actual y que a su vez sean menores que esta.